# How to stream video in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, video, streaming

I am newbie in Android, and  I tried a lot with my code to stream video in emulator, but I am getting exception `"Sorry The application Hellovideodemo(...) has stopped unexpectly`.

Here is the code:

```
 public class HelloVideoDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    // Set video link (mp4 format )
    Uri video = Uri
            .parse("http://dev2010.excoflare.com/zencart/abhishek/BlackBerry_Social_Meeting/av/testing.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();

}
```

}

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the log from the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the Internet permission as a child of the Android Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: But yet the video is unable to stream, this message comes on the screen ,"Cannot play video: Sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device". any help please.

Answer (score 0):

setcontentview that function should have r.id.videoview not main try i guess it should work

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer or meant to be a comment instead; I find your sentence hard to parse.